# Morera's Theorem assumption

Tags: complex-analysis

Morera's theorem states that:
If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ st $\displaystyle \int_C f =0$ for every simple closed curve $C$ on $D$, then $f$ is analytic on $D.$
I am just wondering, what will happen if we remove the continuity in the assumption, will the statement still hold? I cannot think of a counterexample but my gut feel is the statement will be false. Thanks!

Comment: Trivial answer: modify $f$ at a point, then $f$ is not continuous so cannot be analytic.

Comment: If $f$ is locally finite, Borel-measurable and satisfies the assumption on vanishing contour integrals over closed curves, then there exists a holomorphic function $g$ such that $f = g$ a.e.

Comment: For the same reason, if $f$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for any $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and closed simple curve $\gamma$, $\langle f, \int_\gamma \phi(.-z)dz \rangle = 0$ then there is $h$ holomorphic such that $\langle f,\phi \rangle=\langle h,\phi \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x+iy)\phi(x+iy)dxdy$ @SangchulLee

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you have a reference for your claim?

Comment: @AmorFati, One idea is to consider an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ and show that $F$ is holomorphic and that $F' = f$ a.e.